# requests.get(url) in python behaving differently when used in loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, xml-parsing, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm new in python programming and trying to **scrape** every link available in my Urls.txt file.
the code I wrote is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
user_agent = UserAgent()
fp = open("Urls.txt", "r")
values = fp.readlines()
fin = open("soup.html", "a")
for link in values:
    print( link )
    page = requests.get(link, headers={"user-agent": user_agent.chrome})
    html = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    fin.write(str(soup))
```

The code works absolutely fine when the links are provided directly as string instead of as variable but when used as it is the output differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the string you read from the file has a line break.
To remove it use `link.strip("\n")`